# Matching any parameterless function as an argument in scala Mockito

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, specs

I'm trying to verify the following method gets called using Mockito:

```
class Notifier {
  def forward(request: ServletRequest)(onFailure: => Unit) : Unit
}
```

Here's the verification on a mock:

```
val notifier = mock[Notifier]
there was one(notifier).forward(any[ServletRequest])(any[() => Unit])
```

And I get the exception:

```
   The mock was not called as expected: 
    Invalid use of argument matchers!
    3 matchers expected, 2 recorded.
    This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
        //incorrect:
        someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
    When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
    For example:
        //correct:
        someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

I know this is caused by the last parameterless function.  How can I perform a verify properly here?

Comment: `=> Unit` isn't a function type, but a by-name parameter.

Comment: @BenJames so how is `(onFailure: Unit)` different from `(onFailure: => Unit)`?

Comment: The difference is in when the block of code is executed. Having a parameter forward(onFailure: Unit) doesn't make sense. The argument would be evaluated before forward is invoked. With forward(onFailure: => Unit) method forward decides when to evaluate the argument.

Comment: There is a mismatch in the method definition and the expectation. Method forward requires a by-name parameter, the expectation expects an argument that is a function with zero arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try `Function0[Unit]` ?

```
there was one(notifier).forward(any[ServletRequest])(any[Function0[Unit]])
```